# Error while generating a URL from an action : array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a search result view that has a generated list of tables from another sites API. I'm trying to pass off the Artist ID to another next action via GET. The Artist ID will be then used to interact with the API.

I try to pass off the Artist ID like so but I receive a 'array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements'.

The view file in question:

```
    @foreach($parser->Artists->Artist as $Artist)
<table class = "table table-striped">
    <thead>
        {{ var_dump(strval($Artist['ID']))}}
        <h3><a href = "{{ action('ArtistController@detail', strval($Artist['ID'])) }}">{{ $Artist['ListName'] }}</a></h3>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
```

The vardump was to test that a string was in fact being passed off to the action(). I can confirm that it is, before it was a simple XML object.

Here's the corresponding route:

```
Route::get('/artist/detail/{$artist}','ArtistController@detail');
```

And the controller action:

```
<?php

// app/controllers/ArtistController

class ArtistController extends BaseController
{
    public function detail($Artist) {
            return 'Artist ID is ' . $Artist;
    }
{
```

Comment: Could you post your routes.php file?

Comment: Sorry! I thought that might be needed. I just included it.

Comment: Can you tell where is the error coming from by looking at the stack trace?

Comment: try with `action('ArtistController@detail', array('Artist' => strval($Artist['ID'])))`

Comment: Thank you Javi! That was the problem, I understand why too. Laravel is expecting an array not just a string with additonal parameters for an action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Laravel was too smart. My $Artist variable was not read as a string but as a model because of the binding the routes file.

routes.php

```
 Route::model('artist','Artist');
```

I changed $Artist from $Artist_ID and it worked just fine.